# Dagger 2 singleton not working

Tags: android, dagger-2

We are creating a dagger 2 dependency graph

SessionComponent (Session scope) --dependson--->  Appcomponent (Singleton scope) ---dependson---> UserMangerComponent (unscoped... suppose to be singleton)

However, when I inject userManager (a dependency provided by UserManagerComponent), It is not being maintained as singleton. Every injection is creating a new UserManager. Please help ...

I cannot set singleton scope to the dependency.

Comment: did you annotated it with @Singleton ?

Comment: If a dependency is not annotated with any scope then Dagger will inject a new instance every time.

Comment: You should make component per scope, and module by feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed structure is incompatible with how Dagger manages scope.  Only one component in your app should ever be `@Singleton` because each binding within a component that is not exposed via a component interface might be `@Singleton`, but entirely encapsulated in the component implementation.  Thus, each component would hold its own instance and you'd end up with 2 instances rather than one.

Either merge the two components into one `@Singleton` component, create a new scope for your user management, or implement the instance management for your user manager by hand.